# Displaying an HTML file with SVG in WPF

Tags: wpf, svg, webbrowser-control

I need to display an HTML file that has SVG in my WPF application (.net 4.5). I tried the following options

1) Used native web browser control - Didn't work as it does not support SVG.

2) Used chromium web browser control - It works in .net framework 3.5 and 4.0, I               couldn't make it work using .net 4.5.

3) Used CefSharp web browser control -  It works in .net framework 3.5 and 4.0, I               couldn't make it work using .net 4.5.

Can you suggest a work around for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Before pushing to HTML code to browser control you should convert your SVG to PNG and then insert them back to HTML code. Then you push your HTML code to any browser control.